# ServiceStack - OrmLite (probably) - Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

It was working then it fails all of a sudden. Try a few parsing but no luck. 
`Error Code: SqlException`

```
Message Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
```

Stack Trace

[SalesOrderDetailsGet: 14/08/2015 7:59:29 AM]: [REQUEST: {SalesOrderId:676b44dcb0c245a5a3191cda194b3267}] System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read() at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteUtils.ConvertTo[T](IDataReader dataReader, IOrmLiteDialectProvider dialectProvider) at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteResultsFilterExtensions.ConvertTo[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, String sql) at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadCommandExtensions.SingleById[T](IDbCommand dbCmd, Object value) at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadApi.<>c__DisplayClass3c`1.<SingleById>b__3b(IDbCommand dbCmd) at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteExecFilter.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter) at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadExpressionsApi.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter) at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadApi.SingleById[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Object idValue) at BookWS.ServiceLogic.Sales.SalesOrderDataProcess.GetSalesOrderById(Guid id) in C:\Users\Carl\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BookWS\BookWS\BookWS.ServiceLogic\Sales\SalesOrderDataProcess.cs:line 38 at BookWS.ServiceInterface.SalesOrderServices.Get(SalesOrderDetailsGet request) in C:\Users\Carl\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BookWS\BookWS\BookWS.ServiceInterface\Sales\SalesOrderServices.cs:line 40 at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object ) at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequest request, Object instance, TRequest requestDto) ClientConnectionId:0a6a1c79-14e9-4575-9fab-21c542508a78 Error Number:8169,State:2,Class:16

GET:

```
public Object Get(SalesOrderDetailsGet request)
        {
            SalesOrderDataProcess sODP = new SalesOrderDataProcess(Db);
            SalesOrder salesOrderTemp = sODP.GetSalesOrderById(request.SalesOrderId);
```

Data layer:

```
 public SalesOrder GetSalesOrderById(Guid id)
        {
            return _dbConnection.SingleById<SalesOrder>(id);
        }
```

The running stopped at above block's

```
return _dbConnection.SingleById<SalesOrder>(id);
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [common SQL Server exception](https://www.google.com/search?q=Conversion%20failed%20when%20converting%20from%20a%20character%20string%20to%20uniqueidentifier) indicating that it couldn't convert the string value into a **uniqueidentifier** (i.e. GUID).

Go back and ensure all data in your Table has a value for the uniqueidentifier field and that the value is a valid GUID.

Comment: Could you please enlighten me why return _dbConnection.SingleById<SalesOrderItem>(id); throws an exception while  return _dbConnection.SingleWhere<SalesOrderItem>("SalesOrderItemId", id); works?

Comment: @KEIOKRYSHA What is the value of id? Is it a valid guid? What db field is SalesOrderItemId?

Comment: Hi, it is NEWID() generated GUID. So I assume it is valid. the field name of SalesOrderItemId is exactly SalsOrderItemId. It worked until this afternoon, I changed to SingleWhere to get it work. Bizarre.